# Utilizar uma conexão para vários métodos na mesma classe e em outras

Tags: java, mysql

Teria como eu ter somente uma conexão e utilizar ela em vários métodos? Por exemplo:

O *prepared statement* precisa de uma conexão aberta para rodar, então faço o `getConnection()`, e outro método também precisa, então tenho que fazer outro `getConnection()`, não teria como "otimizar" isso?

Comment: Tipo criar uma variável de conexão que vai receber o `getConnection()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essencialmente é assim que se faz. Mas não faz diferença, já é internamente otimizado. Note que ele pega uma conexão, ele não cria uma conexão. Bem, cria se não existir uma.

Claro, tem como fazer isto, armazenar um objeto e ficar passando ele para todo lado na aplicação, e tem gente que gosta de fazer isto (dizem que facilita o teste, mas prejudica a execução normal, deveriam usar outras soluções para facilitar o teste). Mas qual a diferença?

Provavelmente acha que esse `getConnection()` é algo pesado, mas não é, é praticamente a mesma coisa que ficar acessando algo aberto.

Fazendo desta forma alternativa abre possibilidades de cometer algum erro e causar grande confusão posterior e difícil de descobrir onde e porque.

Eu até gosto da ideia de não ficar gerenciando a conexão, mas precisa saber fazer certo, e quase ninguém sabe.

Você pode criar um atributo estático na classe que guarde esta conexão e use o tempo todo, mas é muito fácil manter a conexão ativa mais tempo que o necessário e criar problemas em outras classes, Sem um profundo conhecimento sobre todas as implicações de fazer isto é melhor não fazer. E o ganho seria irrisório, o `getConnection()` é quase a mesma coisa do que vai fazer.

Comment: Se eu fechar a conexão, toda vez que eu pegar ela, irá mudar algo? Por exemplo otimizar?

Comment: O ideal é fechar, se não fizer pode ter problemas.